# DC relay with 2.5V coil voltage and contact voltage of +12V and -12V

Tags: switches, relay

I am working on a project where I need a DC-relay which has 2.5V coil voltage and contact voltage of +12V and  -12V.
My relay should act as a switch. when relay input is 2.5V then it should pass both +12V and -12V otherwise it should stay OFF.

Please let me know if anyone knows which type of relay should I use.

Thanks in Advance.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You most likely cannot operate the relay directly from the output of the LTC6994 so you may as well operate the coil from the incoming +12V making it a much more standard and widely available 12VDC coil DPDT or DPST relay.

Use a transistor. The relay type will depend on the current you are switching and you may have issues if you have a lot of capacitance on the switched side, but that's outside of what I shall presume to be the scope of this question.

If you have a relay coil current up to ~150mA at 12V, you can use a simple circuit such as this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvKNbW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Don't forget the common ground connection needed.